# Scaling performed by gpu::dft with OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, dft

I want to use a GPU-accelerated algorithm, to perform a fast and memory saving dft. But, when I perform the `gpu::dft`, the destination matrix is scaled as it is explained in the [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-dft). How I can avoid this problem with the scaling of the width to `dft_size.width / 2 + 1`? Also, why is it scaled like this? My Code for the DFT is this:

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat d_in, d_out;
d_in = in;
d_out.create(d_in.size(), CV_32FC2 );
cv::gpu::dft( d_in, d_out, d_in.Size );
```

where `in` is a `CV_32FC1` matrix, which is 512x512.

The best solution would be a destination matrix which has the size `d_in.size` and the type `CV_32FC2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [complex conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) symmetry that is present in the output of an FFT. Intel IPP has a [good description](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch10/ch10_real_complex_packed_rcpack2d_format.html) of this packing (the same packing is used by OpenCV). The OpenCV [dft](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=dft#void%20dft%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flags,%20int%20nonzeroRows%29) function also describes this packing.

So, from the [gpu::dft](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html?highlight=dft#void%20gpu%3a%3adft%28const%20GpuMat&%20src,%20GpuMat&%20dst,%20Size%20dft_size,%20int%20flags%29) documentation we have:

> If the source matrix is complex and the output is not specified as real, the destination matrix is complex and has the dft_size size and CV_32FC2 type.

So, make sure you pass a complex matrix to the `gpu::dft` function if you don't want it to be packed. You will need to set the second channel to all zeros:

```
Mat realData;

// ... get your real data...

Mat cplxData = Mat::zeros(realData.size(), realData.type());

vector<Mat> channels;
channels.push_back(realData);
channels.push_back(cplxData);

Mat fftInput;
merge(channels, fftInput);

GpuMat fftGpu(fftInput.size(), fftInput.type());
fftGpu.upload(fftInput);

// do the gpu::dft here...
```

There is a caveat though...you get about a 30-40% performance boost when using CCS packed data, so you will lose some performance by using the full-complex output.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations. This works! If I'll have very big pictures someday, I'll change to the CCS packed data format. Also thanks for the links.

Comment: I'd just like to add that OpenCV's `gpu::dft` does NOT use Intel's CCS format, unlike the non-gpu dft function. Instead it uses cuFFT's packed format. The difference is that CCS is a single channel image of the same dimensions as the real image, and cuFFT is a two-channel image at roughly half the width.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is done for obtaining the result within the range of `+/- 1.0`. This is the most useful form for most applications that need to deal with frequency representation of the data.  For retrieving a result which is not scaled just don't enable the `DFT_SCALE` flag.

**Edit**

The width of the result is scaled, because it is symmetric. So all you have to do is append the former values in a symmetric fashion.

The spectrum is symmetric, because at half of the width the sampling theorem is fulfilled. For example a 2048 point DFT for a signal source with a samplerate of 48 kHz can only represent values up to 24 kHz and this value is represented at half of the width.

Also for reference take a look at [Spectrum Analysis Using the Discrete Fourier Transform](http://cnx.org/content/m12032/latest/).

Comment: I don't mean the scaling of the values of the result of the dft. I mean the scaling of the width of the result.

Comment: yeah...there is my problem: just imagine I have got a 8x8 matrix and I would transform it. My result would be 5x8 and not 4x8. This means, there are columns, I don't have to mirror.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the input, but with the output. Take a look at the answer of @mevatron, maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, too. It was just a thingof the CCS packing I didn't know about. Also thanks for the link.